Remove specific Values From Matplotlib Charts
I want to not shown the 0 values from the charts but I don't want to delete from the column just I want it to become invisible but this code showing the 0 values

percentage_ks = (km_50['Athlete club'].value_counts() / len(km_50)) * 100
top_12 = percentage_ks.nlargest(12)

top_12_new = top_12[top_12 != 0]

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  
sns.barplot(x=top_12_new.index, y=top_12_new.values)

for index, value in enumerate(top_12_new):
    plt.text(index, value + 0.5, f'{value:.2f}%', ha='center')
    
plt.xlabel('Scientific Name')
plt.ylabel('Percentage')
plt.title('Percentage Distribution of Top 15 Scientific Names')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')  

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()



enter image description here

Please provide a [mre] of your input data

IIUC, you want to filter the bars by label, not value, thus you should replace top_12_new = top_12[top_12 != 0] by:
top_12_new = top_12.drop(0, errors='ignore')

Note that an alternative way to compute the percentage could be:
percentage_ks = (km_50['Athlete club'].replace(0, None)
                 .value_counts(dropna=False, normalize=True).mul(100)
                )
top_12 = percentage_ks.nlargest(12)

top_12_new = top_12.drop([None], errors='ignore')

Example output:

Used input:
km_50 = pd.DataFrame({'Athlete club': ([0]*50+list(map(chr, range(65, 65+20))))*100})

